# MySQL: Why can't user with ALL PRIVILEGES create table?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do the right thing (?) and not run MySQL as root all the time. So I have create a user 'jonathan'@'localhost' for which the following privileges are listed:

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for jonathan@localhost                                           |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'jonathan'@'localhost'                            |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `sampledb`.`sampledb` TO 'jonathan'@'localhost' |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

However, when I do:

```
mysql> use sampledb;
Database changed
```

Followed by:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE Person ( 
    ->     id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->     name VARCHAR(100),
    ->     address VARCHAR(200),
    ->     birthdate DATE,
    ->     PRIMARY KEY (id)
    -> );
ERROR 1142 (42000): CREATE command denied to user 'jonathan'@'localhost' for table 'person'
```

It says `CREATE command denied` as visible above. Why doesn't this work? Shouldn't I have 'ALL PRIVILEGES' and doesn't that include `CREATE`?

Comment: @Cyclone amazing duplicate find with _exactly_ the same table-specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you flush privileges after the grant statement?

Answer (score 0):

Have you flushed MySQL's privileges after the `GRANT` by running the following command?

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: yes I have done that

Comment: I actually don't think I would be able to do `SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER` if not cause then it wouldn't show up there I guess? Also, the fact that I could log in at all I take as indicating that the flushing worked...